# How to create a modal window with a tail in CSS?

Tags: css

[image]

I create a triangle:

```css
&--triangle {
        position: absolute;
        top: 40px;
        left: 25%;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 40px solid transparent;
        border-right: 40px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 50px solid $color-white;
        z-index: 999;
    }
```

I create a popup:

```css
&--modal {
        width: 200%;
        @include flexCenter(column);
        min-height: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 70px;
        right: 0;
        background-color: $color-white;
        padding-top: 10px;
        z-index: 998;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);        
        }
    }
```

But I need to have a border and a shadow around the window.

Comment: Set border on the box, set 2 borders for the triangle and make sure the triangle is on top. Oh I see you made triangle with borders, I would just make that with an element so you can apply border to it

Answer (score 1):

I can describe my idea for creating an arrow illusion on the popup. We can draw the arrow as a separate square, which can be rotated and placed over the popup to create the desired effect. It should be positioned precisely over the popup to overlap part of the popup's border. It is important to ensure that the content of the popup appears over this arrow. Since the arrow is a separate element, we can add borders and shadows to it. While borders can be added without any issues, adding a shadow to the arrow would cause it to overlap the popup. To fix it, we can add the shadow as a separate element placed behind the popup. [Example of my explanation](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-dust-d6oo53)